# MSBI Merge:how to merge an excel file with a test file in SSIS?

Tags: excel, csv, merge

How to merge an excel file with a test file in SSIS?

I have tried to merge an Excel file with a text file using Merge in SSIS, but it is throwing error as `[Flat File Source [41]] Error: Data conversion failed`. The data conversion for column "Title " returned status value 4 and status text `Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.`

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set OutputColumn size to 255 from Flat File Connection Manager Editor by clicking on Advance and selecting each column. For example, I have four columns Name, Title, Company, and Location. For those columns, first I've changed data types to Unicode string [DT_WSTR] as txt files have string [DT_STR] because Excel file has Unicode data types. Also, set the OutputColumn size to 255.